# Wether I use firebase or google_mobile_ad packages I still get the following >Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, sdk, admob

### I updated my AndroidManifest file as following:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />

           
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-7900637135395566/4052728178"
        />
```

### I also made some changes to my build.gradle file as following:

````
    ```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 30
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.richest"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
````

}

```
dependencies {
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.0.0'
}
```

### I also updated the dart-SDK version to the latest one .However I still get the following exception

`E/AndroidRuntime(11367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(11367): Process: com.example.richest, PID: 11367 E/AndroidRuntime(11367): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:  E/AndroidRuntime(11367):  E/AndroidRuntime(11367): ****************************************************************************** E/AndroidRuntime(11367): * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          * E/AndroidRuntime(11367): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         * E/AndroidRuntime(11367): * to find your app ID.                                                       * E/AndroidRuntime(11367): ****************************************************************************** E/AndroidRuntime(11367):  E/AndroidRuntime(11367):  E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6948) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6540) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6480) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:231) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1889) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7422) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) E/AndroidRuntime(11367): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:  E/AndroidRuntime(11367):  E/AndroidRuntime(11367): ****************************************************************************** E/AndroidRuntime(11367): * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          * E/AndroidRuntime(11367): * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         * E/AndroidRuntime(11367): * to find your app ID.                                                       * E/AndroidRuntime(11367): ****************************************************************************** E/AndroidRuntime(11367):  E/AndroidRuntime(11367):  E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzt.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:24) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:3) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6945) E/AndroidRuntime(11367):    ... 10 more`

Comment: Try uninstalling the app and reinstalling it worked for me.

Comment: I did change the whole app but I still get the same exception !